Tour or Tore Pronunciation
In the past few years newsmen and sportscasters have changed the pronunciation of tour (rhymes with lure) to tore (rhymes with wore).
Why is this?

"newsmen and sportscasters" on what channel(s)?

Where? This happens in both the UK and the US but is much more pervasive in the former.

Are you sure that the same people don't pronoounce lure like lore, sure like shore, and moor like more?

I don't think I pronounce lure and wore very differently. If there's a difference, it's very subtle.

I disagree completely with your peremptory statement regarding sportscasters and newsmen [sic].

@Barmar So for you lure and wore aren't just like loo + R and woe + R respectively? Are you perhaps then from New England or Old, and are you a rhotic speaker?

I live in New England now, but I grew up on Long Island, NY. I pronounce them like "lawr" and "wawr", rhyming with "or". @tchrist

@Barmar So yup, you have a lax vowel there: /lɔr/ and /wɔr/. You may not have much R there at all. Those of us with the more typical American pre-R tensing and pre-R  neutralization have tense /lur/ and tense /wor/, which are both different from your lax vowel. I think it has something to do with how we scrunch up our tongue in the back so much for that R sound, but don't quote me on that. :)

What’s going on is that you’re now hearing more people whose
accents differ from your own. But there are various subtle
phenomena at work here that make this sound this way to your ear
even though that may not actually be what they’re saying
after all.
What you’ve described is mainly the difference between the /u/
vowel of words like two, who, coot and the /o/ vowel of words
like toe, oak, coat. You’re used to hearing the /u/ vowel in
tour, and not used to hearing the /o/ vowel there.
So am I. And when I first started hearing some people talk about
things like tourism with /o/ not /u/ as though it were tore
plus ‑ism, it sounded quite odd to me. Honestly, it still does,
probably because I don’t hear it that way very often and so when
I do, it stands out more.
Standard broadcast American English did not use to have
tour pronounced that /o/ way, because the particular accent
they worked towards does not do that. But now that regional
dialects don’t get filed off anymore, or not as much, and because
you’re now hearing more people from all over the place, you’re
starting to notice these small variations. It’s actually a
recency illusion because the folks who do this have “always” done
it, or at least for many generations.
You may well be listening to speakers who do have the /o/
vowel there, but then again, you might not. They might actually
be saying the /ʊ/ vowel of words like took, put, should; either
that one, or else the /ɔ/ vowel of words like taught, all, dog.
But if they were, you wouldn’t hear it that way.
That’s because there’s an R following the vowel, and for most
speakers of English today any “tenseness” distinction is
“neutralized” before an R. (This only counts for people who
actually pronounce an R, though. Some do not.) That means you
can’t hear that difference, and you hear it as the sound you
yourself make (or think you make).  This is part of the issue of
the Mary–marry–merry merger that most of us have, amongst
others like the north–force a.k.a. the horse–hoarse merger
or the cure–force merger.
So here’s what’s going on. Vowels like /o/ and /u/ respectively of toke and
coot are tense vowels, whereas vowels like /ɔ/ and /ʊ/ respectively of
tall and took are lax vowels. (You might have learned to call
these “long” and “short” vowels instead of
“tense” and “lax” vowels as I’m doing here. Other writings you might run across call those “close” versus “open” vowels, or “free” versus “checked” vowels.)
It turns out that many speakers from the British Isles, along with
a few North Americans mostly from New England, use a lax vowel
there, probably /ɔ/ as in Paul. But because you yourself use a
tense vowel there and because you neutralize the tense–lax
distinction before phonemic R, you hear them ɴᴏᴛ as saying
/tɔr/ like they hear themselves, but rather /tor/ like you hear yourself say it.
That’s part of how neutralization works.
The Wikipedia article on vowel changes before historic R
specifically calls out the pronunication tour here:

Cure–force merger
In Modern English, the reflexes of Early Modern English /uːr/
and /iur/ are highly susceptible to phonemic mergers with other
vowels. Words belonging to that class are most commonly spelled
with oor, our, ure, or eur. Examples include poor, tour,
cure, Europe (words such as moor ultimately from Old English
ō words). Wells refers to the class as the cure words after
the keyword of the lexical set to which he assigns them.
In traditional Received Pronunciation and General American,
cure words are pronounced with Received Pronunciation /ʊə/
(/ʊər/ before a vowel) and General American /ʊr/. However,
those pronunciations are being replaced by other pronunciations
in many accents.
In Southern England, cure words are often pronounced with
/ɔː/ and so moor is often pronounced /mɔː/, tour /tɔː/, and
poor /pɔː/. The traditional form is much more common in
Northern England. A similar merger is encountered in many
varieties of American English, whose prevailing pronunciations
are [oə] and [or]⁓[ɔr], depending on whether or not the accent
is rhotic.

Note the very last sentence cited immediately above, the one I’ve set in bold. Professor Lawler talks about this here, as I do here including this chart which shows which vowels are tense and which vowels are lax in American English:

Please see the list of linked questions for much more detailed
treatments of this curiosity.

newscasters and sportscasters? A bit much. Not that your explanation is wrong by any means but you might have pointed out the speciousness of the OP's aural observation.

@Lambie It was not I who mentioned newscasters and sportscasters. But I did mention the tricks the mind can play under neutralization.

No, it wasn't but you begin your answer as if the statement were credible re those people. It's just not on. Do you really think he has been hearing this from news people recently and everywhere? Pa-lease.

@Lambie You seem to be reading more into what he said than I am. You seem to be reading him as having said that ᴀʟʟ newscasters and ᴀʟʟ sportscasters everywhere are now suddenly always saying the word in this new weird way under some bizarre coördination theory. That's not my read, which is simply that he's of late begun to notice how sᴏᴍᴇ news- and sportscasters have pronunciations of this word which differ from his own: a perfectly reasonable observation to make, ɴᴏᴛ one deserving of ridicule. Please stop using over-the-top sarcasm here: it does not work on the internet.

I hate this kind of question because it is simply not true. He may be hearing it, yes, but is he only hearing it from those people? Personally, I have never heard anyone say golf tore, for tour. So, he might have heard it but it isn't all over the place. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBQGHiuqZoU

@Lambie "Tour" and "tore" are definitely homophones to me, with a sound that seems to be a diphthong of 'long o' and the r-colored vowel. It's surprising that Merriam Webster doesn't list this variant at all: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tour since it seems pretty common. But, "sure" (with only the r-colored vowel and no dipthong) doesn't sound like "shore," and "lure" (same thing) doesn't sound like "lore," so it's not the same merger Peter Shore is referring to. (Although, "moor" and "more" do rhyme with each other and with "tour", so maybe it's a partial one?)

@Lambie: Then you haven't been listening closely. There are lots of Americans who say "my golf tore" (mainly from the Midwest, I believe — but I could easily be wrong).  And this vowel merger is even more prevalent in British English, which I suspect is what the OP has been listening to.

Both "tour" and "tore' use something like /ʊ/ to me.

@QuackE.Duck: The phoneme combination /ʊr/ has completely disappeared from many people's speech, but it doesn't always get replaced by the same sounds, so the (partial) mergers aren't consistent. For some people, lure, sure, cure, purr, and fur all rhyme, but they don't rhyme with tour or moor.

No, they keep the ‘y’ sound, but only in cure. But people don’t generally consider that this keeps the words from rhyming. After all, people also consider that fjord rhymes with cord.

@QuackE.Duck I don't think BrE speakers pronounce tore and  tour the same way.

@Lambie: you're overgeneralizing. A lot of them do, but some of them don't. Forvo.com

@QuackE.Duck Are doers and Dewars and doors all homophones for you then? What about newer and nor, or boor and bore and booer (one who boos)? How about an icy Coors and some icy cores? What about cures and queuers, and are those also like cores? And you’re and your and ewer and yore? And wooer (one who woos) and who’re, and are those like wore and war and whore?

@tchrist 3 sets: doers, Dewars, newer, booer, queuers, ewer, wooer, who’re then doors, nor, boor, bore, Coors, cores, your, yore, wore, whore, war and finally cures, you’re, your (because your could be either way) First group = 2 syllables; 2nd and 3rd are 1 syllable

Each set rhymes but not with the other sets.

@tchrist In an earlier comment, I didn't realize the "ʊ" symbol meant a short "u," not a long "u"! I see how that would have been confusing -- my bad (or 'bag' if you prefer :D). To the best of my (very limited) familiarity with IPA notation, the actual vowel sound in set 1 should be /uːɚ/, and in set 3 /ɚ/ (like in "cure" here https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cure). I really don't know how to represent the one from set 2, but it's like Merriam Webster's interactive example for the word "or" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/or (Too bad MW doesn't have an entry for 'newer.')

...Also deleted the comment with the wrong symbol

What's essentially going on in this case is something linguists call the "cure-force merger", whereby the 'ur' sound is assimilated into the 'or' sound. which itself can merge with the 'goat' vowel, thus creating what linguists call the "dough-door merger".

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
